# React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child

Tags: react-native, react-redux

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import Login from './js/components/Login';
import userReducers from './js/reducers/user';

import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

let store = createStore(combineReducers({userReducers}));

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Login />
    );
  }
}

export default class Testextends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store = {store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
      // <View>
      //   <Text>jhdgf</Text>
      // </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Test', () => Test);
```

It gives me following error:

[image]

I'm trying one basic example of react-native with redux. If I remove TouchableHighlight also , the error still persists. Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: hey, I'm facing the same issue right now. did you manage to find the root cause for this?

Answer (score 0):

Its doesn't seems you're doing something wrong, on the code pasted, are you sure the error came from this part of your code ?

Maybe try to put between `()` your `TouchableHighlight` component, but I don't think that's going to change something...

Or try a ternary rather than a binary operation.

Also be sure that you import `TouchableHighlight` and `Text` from `react-native`.

Comment: Magrin I debugged the whole code once again and found that error is in <Provider store = {store}> in index.android.js. Below is the code:

Comment: Ok try this: `<Provider store={store}>{ () => <App /> }</Provider>` and remove all the commented lines in the return

Comment: Magrin No effect. Error is still there. Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete all not  necessary white space

```
<View>{ !this.props.user.loggedIn &&
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onLoginButtonPress}>
            <Text>Login</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
}</View>
```

Because in the following example

```
 <View> {...}</View>
```

you have two children: first white space and second all in curved brackets.

Comment: Space will resume in an other error in react-native:
RawText " " must be wrapped in an explicit <Text> component.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with the following React Native code:

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-native'

<Link to={props.url}>{props.title}</Link>
```

Spend few hours trying to understand why the similar code works in WEB but not in native view. There is no viable error messaging or hints from the React Native runtime on which component causes this failure, so it's insanely hard to identify the issue.

Managed to fix this crash by doing the following:

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-native'
import {Text} from "react-native";

<Link to={props.url}><Text>{props.title}</Text></Link>
```

Looks like the `title` text was treated as multiple elements, so we ended up with such an error.

This is not a solution for the subject. But, because there are so many ways to fail with this error in React Native, it may be useful to put this another example of such a crash for those who Googled and ended here.

Answer (score 0):

First off, "export default class Testextends Component" should actually be "export default class *Test extends* Component"

the reason why that error is thrown is because the Provider component takes only one element.
for Example:
wrong:

```
<provider store = {store}>
 <div/>
<div/>
<provider>
```

correct:

```
<provider store = {store}>
 <App/>
<provider>
```

which you did correctly, if you commented the  component. Try the class error and see if it works.